# How do skulltula requirements split across two players?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

Let's say a skulltula has a requirement like "Do not take more than 4 hearts of damage". If I'm playing co-op, does that mean we each can't take more than 4 hears, or we can't take more than 4 hearts total? What about other numeric requirements?

Comment: I do know that the kill requirements are spread across both players, so I would assume that the others are as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirements are shared for both players.

That means that if you need to kill X number of enemies, it considers the kills from both players, and both players cannot lose more than X number of hearts between them. If a challenge specifies that a player must maintain above X% of their health (I believes there's 2 of these), that threshold must be maintained by both players.

Playing co-op can be both a curse and a blessing in this regard! Though I found it *very* useful to have a partner when tackling bosses with a time limit.

Answer (score -2):

Yep I was just looking for the same answer to this question! It seems to be combined.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back that up?