# How are damage requirements for skulltulas counted?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

If a requirement for a skulltula says "Do not take more than X hearts of damage", does that mean ever, or at once? As in, if X is 4, and I take three hearts, heal up to full, then take another two hearts, have I met the requirement?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I believe it means cumulative.  So if four hearts was the requirement, using your example, you would not meet the requirement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do skulltula requirements split across two players?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189911/how-do-skulltula-requirements-split-across-two-players)

Comment: Err, I'm asking two different questions about the game mechanic, they're not dupes